# Passar a música como parâmetro de pagina html

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-audio, áudio

Boas, estou a tentar fazer um menu de jogo em *HTML5 + JavaScript + CSS3* e quando clico num botão quero que mude a página *html*, mas que a mesma música continue a dar.

Suponho que seja com o método *audio.currentTime*, mas não sei passar como parâmetro. Para mudar de página estou a usar o método *window.location.assign(ficheiro html).*

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com "mas que a música continue a mudar" ?

Comment: Continue a dar* já editei

Comment: Mas referes-te à mesma música no mesmo sítio ou que começe a "dar"/tocar sozinha? Tens mesmo de recarregar a página?

Comment: À mesma música no mesmo sítio. Eu suponho que tenha de recarregar a página visto que o botão redireciona-me para outro menu.

Comment: O mais fácil para você é usar jQuery para requisitar as páginas. Assim no clique você carrega a página dentro de uma div sem atualizar todo o documento. E a música continua a tocar. Se quiser uma referência para abrir a página dentro da div acesse http://www.codigosnaweb.com/forum/Enviando-dados-via-POST-ou-GET-com-jQuery_3_2830.html